# Access server-side data with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I'm building a MEAN app so the backend uses Express with EJS templating and I want to use Angular for any client-side stuff.

What's the *best-practise* method to access server-side properties in your client-side? So for example, to create a user-profile page I'd have the following:

Route ( uses [passport](http://passportjs.org)):

```
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    res.render('profile.ejs', {
        user: req.user
    });
});
```

Profile.ejs

```
...
<div>
    <%= user.email %>
</div>
...
```

So rather than mixing EJS expressions with Angular's expressions (curly brackets). How can I access user.email in Angular's $scope?

Comment: Using Angular you'd usually separate your data/resources into a RESTful structure that your client can consume via JSON instead of rendering them into your templates. You can serve (mostly) static HTML then.

Comment: What's the best way to do that? (any good examples?)

Comment: Guess this might help: http://briantford.com/blog/angular-express

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to do than creating (unnecessary) API calls to retrieve server-side info?

Comment: Well, if you want to build a single page application (i.e. Angular) that's the way to go. If you want to build an *old-school* webapp that's fine too. You'll probably have a hard time mixing the two approaches though.

Comment: Nah that's fine. How does/can this affect performance?

Comment: Hard to tell, if you're doing it right you'll have no problems :)

Comment: You can point Angular templates to use templates returned by server side.